# Dynamically inject PHP as form action redirects to 404 page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So what I'm doing is dynamically creating a form and input elements in a document with JS like so:

```
document.ondblclick = function(e) {
  if (e.clientX < 50 && e.clientY > window.innerHeight - 50
  && !document.querySelector('form')) {
    const b = document.body
    const f = document.createElement('form')
    const i = document.createElement('input')
    b.style.width = '100vw'
    b.style.height = '100vh'
    b.style.margin = '0'
    b.style.display = 'flex'
    b.style.justifyContent = 'center'
    b.style.alignItems = 'center'
    i.setAttribute('type', 'password')
    i.setAttribute('name', 'password')
    i.setAttribute('id', 'form')
    f.setAttribute('method', 'post')
    f.setAttribute('action', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>')
    f.appendChild(i)
    b.appendChild(f)
    i.focus()
    i.onblur = function() {
      i.focus()
    }
  }
}
```

However, it's as if the browser ignores the PHP and, instead of returning to the current file, consequently gets redirected to the 404 page.

Below is the HTML, PHP, and the file structure of the directory.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    include "php/connect.php";
    $stri = "SELECT password FROM account";
    $stat = $conn->prepare($stri);
    $stat->execute();
    $resu = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($_POST["password"], $resu["password"])) {
      $_SESSION["session"] = $resu["password"];
      $conn = null;
      echo 'SUCCESS';
    }
    $conn = null;
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>&lrm;</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The directory is structured like so...

```
public_html >
    trading-toolbox > 
        css > index.css
        js  > index.js
        php > connect.php
        index.php
```

**Why is it redirecting to the 404 page? What am I doing wrong here? Is the action attribute of the form treated as a string since it is set dynamically with JS?**

Comment: i think i might understand what's happening. the error logs are fairly straightforward. let me run a few tests quickly. if i figured it out ill delete the question.

Comment: never mind. i'm dumbfounded. i tried hard setting a url into the action attribute, but that doesn't work either

Comment: I'm just curious to why you are using `php` within the `javascript` for something that can simply be done in `javascript`? You could replace `'<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>'` with `window.location.pathname` Also if your `javascript` is an external file then your `php` won't run as it isn't a server-side/format.

Comment: @NewToJS because i don't want the final destination to be evident on the client side

Comment: @NewToJS any idea what's going on here? it doesn't seem to be recognizing the PHP as PHP :/

Comment: But it will be seen. You are sending the client to that with with the form data and all the client as to do is inspect element to see the `action` attributes value which would show the same as using `window.location.pathname`. **Also** if your `javascript` is an *external file* then your `php` won't run as it isn't a server-side file.

Comment: @NewToJS the only thing that would be seen on the client side is `f.setAttribute('action', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>')`, whereas the actual redirection occurs in the PHP of the `index.php` page which runs on the server or is at least supposed to run on the server when the page, `index.php`, gets redirected to itself...

Comment: It looks like your code seems to have other issues which are leading to your errors. `inc/connect.php` doesn't appear to exist, which results in `$conn` being null.

Comment: Also, give us your folder structure. Is the file with `f.setAttribute('action', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>')` in a .php file?

Comment: @FrankerZ ohhh those were outdated logs :/

Comment: @FrankerZ i'll add the file structure right now. nono, that bit is in a `.js` file, `index.js`

Comment: @FrankerZ i've updated my question and added that info!

Comment: Like I said before *"Also if your javascript is an external file then your php won't run as it isn't a server-side file."*

Comment: @NewToJS i understand that much. the PHP isn't being executed in the JS file. the PHP is injected into a PHP file as a string via JS...

Comment: Make index.js a php file (Call it js.php or something else, and include it like normal ie. `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.php"></script>`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your index.js file. Notice the file ending? `.js` is a javascript file, and will be treated by your server as a static file, only serving the contents and not processing the file. The easiest solution is to rename it to `index.php` and then include it like normal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.php"></script>
```

Comment: hm... it's being injected into the PHP file (index.php), though?

Comment: i mean, if worse comes to worse, i could just do that, include the `<script type="text/javascript">...the contents of index.js...</script>` in `index.php`

Comment: You say "it's being injected into the PHP file.". It's not...though. It's being rendered out to your browser, and when the browser sees the script tag, it makes another request back up to the server in order to request the "js/index.js" file. When your server finds the file, it just serves it as javascript. What do you mean "if worse comes to worse". Is really renaming a file the end of the world?

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh so what youre saying is that `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is referring to `index.js` in the way in which it's all structured? i mean "if worse comes to worse" as in i prefer segregating my code. all JS in the JS folder, all CSS in the CSS folder, etc.

Comment: @Anthony can you post your files structure, to understand your problem

Comment: @MauricioFlorez it's posted already in my original question near the bottom ;)

Comment: @FrankerZ i don't. i really appreciate the gesture, though. it honestly isn't that important. i mean, as you noted, making the JS inline works fine and accomplishes the objective of leaving the redirection on the server side. at this point this is more a matter of curiosity than being an actual issue. thanks again for the gesture <3

Comment: It's more the understanding of how server side/client side work. If you have google chat, or another voice platform, I can walk you through/give you a quick rundown.

Comment: i got teamspeak and discord. i gotta hit the hay tho. maybe sometime this week if youre free and i have some time? really appreciate it, again <3

Answer (score 1):

You need name your .js file as .php and send headers for expose the file as javascript and use $_SESSION to send the action file from index to JS

```
<?php
header('content-type:application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
?>
...
f.setAttribute('action', '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["formFile"]); ?>')
...
```

Then in your index file add and change

```
<?php $_SESSION["formFile"] = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.php"></script>
```

Comment: very interesting!! i will try that tomo. when i have some more time. compared to making the JS inline, this is def more along the lines of what i was hoping for

Comment: there wouldn't be any issues with the following piece of code, `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.PHP"></script>`??? and what exactly is the purpose of creating `$_SESSION["formFile"]`, why not just use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` instead of reassigning it to another variable?

Comment: Nop you need name that file as .php so that PHP preprocesor can read your file, if not your file will be a static file and the php code will not be readed.

Comment: Setting the content type should not be required. Any recent browser will see js/index.php in the script, and just parse it as javascript.